# 3D Acceleration In Android Emulator

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

Is there any way to have 3D acceleration in the Android emulator? We are attempting to do 3D gfx in a course here at the university, but not all the students have android devices. So we need better gfx performance out of the emulator.

We are using windows as our development environment.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Todd
Millersville University

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Have a look at [libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) - it will allow you to develop at full speed on the PC, and then deploy to android later.

Comment: we are looking to use the min3D [link](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/). We have the framework, just not an accelerated emulator.

Comment: Are you fixed on using min3D? A libGDX program runs natively on both PC and android, so no emulator is needed. As I mentioned, there is no accelerated emulator for android, so I don't know what else you can do to develop 3D android apps at full speed without a device.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ADT 17 and SDK Tools r17](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/03/21/for-developers-adt-17-sdk-tools-r17-and-support-package-r7-released-with-new-features-and-fixes-for-lint-build-system-and-emulator/) that was released yesterday.  It adds support for hardware accelerated graphics rendering in the emulator.